# Contract is NOT deployed Despite calling truffle migrate

Tags: truffle-migration

I'm trying to call a contract I've created.
I've set up my truffle deployment script like so:

```
var SafeYieldAggregator = artifacts.require("SafeYieldAggregator")

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SafeYieldAggregator);
};
```

I've Run:

truffle compile
truffle migrate

Which returns the output:

> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
> √ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

Inside my app I attach my truffle contract
$.getJSON('SafeYieldAggregator.json', function(data) {
// Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with @truffle/contract
var safeYieldArtifact = data;
App.contracts.SafeYieldAggregator = TruffleContract(safeYieldArtifact);

```
  // Set the provider for our contract
  App.contracts.SafeYieldAggregator.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
});
```

And then I try to call my contract:

```
 App.contracts.SafeYieldAggregator.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    yieldAggregatorInstance = instance;

    // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
    return yieldAggregatorInstance.supply(1, {from: account});
  })
```

I get an error:

> Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

My best guess is that truffle thinks this has been deployed appropriately.  My config is setup like:

```
networks: {
  development: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 8545,
    network_id: "*" // Match any network id
  },
  develop: {
    port: 8545
  }
}
```

and I'm running the ganache-cli on the same port forking the main net

Answer (score 2):

You can try executing the following command:

```
 truffle develop
 compile -all
 migrate --reset
```

If this still doesn't work, make some changes to your contract, such as adding a space.You can try, and God bless you!

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you executed that JS migration file before. If you do `truffle migrate`, Truffle will not run previous successful migrations again (even though you modified your contract). You can read more about it under **When are migrations executed** https://blockheroes.dev/complex-migration/.

To redeploy all contracts again just run `truffle migrate --reset`